# How could I produce/rig this flame-colour lottery?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, combustion, chemistry-in-fiction

Not sure if this is the wrong SE for this, happy to move it if not...

In the Netflix TV series [*Sabrina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilling_Adventures_of_Sabrina_(TV_series)), there is a scene where people take part in an appropriately-gothic-and-ominous lottery, which proceeds as follows:

1. Fourteen participants draw, one at a time, pieces of paper from a box.  The papers are all blank and have no differences visible to the human eye in the (rather moody) lighting.
2. The participants burn their paper in the flame of a candle which is in front of them.  There is a separate candle for each participant, but they all appear to burn with the same yellow flame.
3. Twelve of the papers burn up quickly, like flash paper.  The other papers burn more slowly, and release red (for the 'runner up') or white (for the 'winner') smoke, respectively.
4. > The runner up waits on the winner hand and foot for three days, and then the winner is killed and eaten cannibalistically, with a strong religious 'ascension' dogma.

Depending on your point of view, this is a lottery you may or may not want to win, and also one which there would be great advantage in being able to rig to ensure a particular winner.  So my questions are:

What chemistry could you use in the papers and candles to achieve the effects shown?

Comment: Don't think this will be answered here. Pictures may help

Comment: I removed the follow up questions as they are too broad to answer.

Comment: @A.K. some sort of "identify" tag.  Sci-fi-and-fantasy SE, for instance, has [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), which is "I remember this story where X happened, can anyone identify what it was?".  I guess I'd be looking for a tag which meant "suggest chemistry which could result in X _non-scientific_ effect".

Comment: As another example question in the same style, I remember from my school days a demonstration with two clear beakers of liquid, a white rag and a bottle of dark pigment.  He splattered the pigment on the rag, then dunked the rag in the first beaker, causing the whole beaker to turn black.  Then he removed the rag, which had also become black, and dunked it in the other beaker; the liquid bleached the pigment from the rag, and when he then moved the rag back to the other beaker, the rag bleached the pigment from the liquid.  The whole demonstration was accompanied by a religious narrative.

Comment: I believe part of the reason we don't have an [tag:identify] tag is it is not helpful for drawing attention from needed individuals. not a bad suggestion though.

Comment: There is a tag [tag:identification], but we have already talked about removing it, because it is a meta tag. It simply doesn't help in determining which chemistry it would belong to. cc @A.K.

Comment: I think the question (as it is now) is fine and there are probably a few (but narrow in scope) legit answers. I would recommend keeping it open and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smokeless and quick burning isn't hard to achieve, just use [flash paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrocellulose). For white smoke, I would use flash paper again but with a white oxide powder such as titanium oxide with a flame retardant to slow the burn. For red, again flash paper but, you need a compound that releases bromine when burned. I think [copper(i) bromide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(I)_bromide) or [silver(i) bromide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bromide) would be ideal as both are easy to decompose and tolerant to moisture in air, though silver bromide is not tolerant to prolonged light exposure. These salts may discolor the paper and you may need to color the non-red smoke papers to make them all look the same.

Comment: I don't think bromine is a good way to get red in a flame and is certainly not safe (though given the context this might not be an issue). Surely a strontium salt would be better?

Comment: @matt_black red smoke, not flame. And yes bromine is not the best, but given the context I would not worry about the irritating smoke.